# error $ operator not defined for this s4 class in r (normalization)

Tags: r

I am trying to normalize transactions data.

```
credit <- read.transactions("directory",sep=",", header="TRUE")
ind <- sample(2, nrow(credit), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
trainData <- credit[ind==1, ]
testData <- credit[ind==2, ]
testData$amount<- ((testData$amount - min(testData$amount)) / (max(testData$amount) - 
min(testDat$amount)))
```

However, the following error is returned.

```
Error in testData$amount : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Operator `@`? As in `testData@amount` or maybe `testData@.Data$amount`. Check `str(testData)` to see its structure or the Value section of the function that created that object.

Comment: Perhaps try using `@` instead of `$` ; if this does not solve it can you try to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please including any library calls.

Comment: in your calculation you forgot a 'a' at the end of min(testDat[!!a!!]$amount